# What does "landing" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The manager shall assess the fall area for building infrastructure, (i.e.,
>   fire escapes, landings, access ladders) that could impede the fall path.

What does "landings" mean in this context? It seems to be a place for landing, but it's still vague. What does it exactly refer to? I searched a dictionary, but the definition is just "a floor between two sets of stairs or at the top of a set of stairs".

And I have one more question. How should "for" be interpreted? Does it mean that:

> the manager shall assess the fall area "of" building infrastructure

or

> the manager shall assess the fall area "regarding" the building
>   infrastructure (which means that the manager inspects the fall area,
>   and the inspection is about building infrastructure)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A building Landing is referring to something like what is pictured below:

[image]

Also, for can be interpreted as your latter statement:

> the manager shall assess the fall area "regarding" the building infrastructure (which means that the manager inspects the fall area, and the inspection is about building infrastructure)

Answer (score 1):

A landing is like a flat area protruding from the main structure. The dictionary refers to these transitory areas between the staircase and where the staircase goes as landings. So it could be that, or some kind of access platform, or a pathway. A balcony is a landing. A rooftop (again, shorter than the tower it is apparently attached to) can be a landing. There's more than one way to assess that word.

"For" is linked to "assess." The manager is "assessing X for Y." We can switch that out for some synonyms which may clarify it for you.

> The manager shall inspect the fall area to find building infrastructure...